# How to get Spotify Followers/Following list

Tags: javascript, arrays, spotify

So what I want to do is scrape all the followers and followings of a profile.
e.g:
User Mali is following: x,y,z,t
User Mali is followed by: x,y
Users not following back Mali: z
Users Mali is not following: t

I used to do this with selenium where I would go to a users profile and scrape the names of all followers and following but chrome is auto-uptading and my driver stays outdated.